# Packages does not exists while building a gradle project

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I want to build a gradle project from the project https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services. The difference from this project from GH is that I added the main `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'com.web.WebApplication'
```

I used the command

```
gradle build --stacktrace
```

to build a project, but it crashes me
https://pastebin.com/5bnex9xs

e.g. `error: cannot find symbol` or `error: package does not exists`

The application compiles correctly in Intellij https://zapodaj.net/d11780c416ad8.png.html

What could be the reason for this error?